# PHP: is there an isLetter() function or equivalent?

Tags: php, function, letters

I am no PHP expert. I am looking for the PHP equivalent of [isLetter()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isLetter%28char%29) in Java, but I can't find it. Does it exist?

I need to extract letters from a given string and make them lower case, for example: "Ap.ér4i5T i6f;" should give "apéritif'. So, yes, there are accentuated characters in my strings.

Comment: `strtolower` will give you the lower-case string, but you'll likely need a regex to parse the input string and just get the alpha characters from it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`ctype_alpha()`](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alpha.php).

Comment: Don't forget to use `setlocale()` because in the default C locale, only [a-zA-Z] will be considered as alphabetic characters (no accentuated characters)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to regex / preg_replace, you can also use strtoupper($string) and strtolower($string), if you need to universally upper-case a string. As Konrad mentioned, preg_replace is probably your best bet though.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtoupper.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php

Answer (score 1):

In PHP (and in Java) you wouldn’t use `isLetter` to implement it, you’d rather replace all characters that aren’t letters using a regular expression:

```
echo preg_replace('/\P{L}/', '', input);
```

Loop up the documentation of [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) and the [regex pattern syntax desciption](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php), in particular the relevant [Unicode character classes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php).

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use the [php-slugs](http://code.google.com/p/php-slugs/) source code, with appropriate modifications.