# How can I check if a char is a letter or a number?

Tags: php, numbers, letter

I have a string and I want to loop it so that I can check if every char is a letter or number.

```
$s = "rfewr545 345b";

for ($i=1; $i<=strlen($s); $i++){
   if ($a[$i-1] == is a letter){
      echo $a[$i-1]." is a letter";
   } else {
      echo $a[$i-1]." is a number";
   }
}
```

How can I check if a char is a letter or a number?

Comment: Is it possible to use a regular expression on the whole string instead of iterating over each character?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/q/9721636/1169798 and http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php

Comment: `is_numeric()` should do the trick for checking numbers.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To test if character `is_numeric`, use:

```
is_numeric($a[$i-1])
```

As below:

```
$s = "rfewr545 345b";
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($s); $i++){
   $char = $s[$i];
   if (is_numeric($char)) {
      echo $char . ' is a number';
   } else {
      echo $char . ' is a letter';
   }
}
```

Comment: Not every char that is not numeric is a letter!!

Comment: What about multibyte chars ?

Answer (score 23):

You can use:

[ctype_digit](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-digit.php)

and

[ctype_alpha](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alpha.php)

Comment: There is ctype_alnum($character) too, just for information.

Answer (score 6):

With regular expressions you can try the following.

**Test for a number**

```
if (preg_match('/\d/', $char)) :
     echo $char.' is a number';
endif;
```

**Test for a "letter"**

```
if (preg_match('/[a-zA-Z]/', $char)) :
     echo $char.' is a letter';
endif;
```

The benefit of this approach is mainly from the "letter" test, which lets you efficiently define what *constitutes* as a "letter" character. In this example, the basic English alphabet is defined as a "letter".

Comment: preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z\s\,]+$/')

Comment: I believe OP refers to testing a single *letter* character, not *words*.

Answer (score 1):

See this:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php

```
if(Is_numeric($char)) {
//Do stuff
}
else {
//Do other stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do by using **is_numeric()** function

```
if (is_numeric($a[$i-1])){
      echo $a[$i-1]." is a number";
   } else {
      echo $a[$i-1]." is a letter";
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

php provide some nice function to checkout chars. Use the apt functions as conditions in if blocks.

visit:

[PHP char functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.ctype.php)

e.g. **ctype_digit** returns true if number is numeric.

Answer (score 0):

You may use [ctype_alpha](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alpha.php) to check for alphabetic character(s).

Similarly, you may use [ctype_digit](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-digit.php) to check for numeric character(s).

**`is_numeric` — Finds whether a variable is a number or a numeric string**

`is_numeric()` example:

```
<?php

    $tests = array(
        "42",
        0b10100111001,
        "not numeric",
        array(),
        9.1
    );

    foreach ($tests as $element) {
        if (is_numeric($element)) {
            echo "'{$element}' is numeric", PHP_EOL;
        } else {
            echo "'{$element}' is NOT numeric", PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
?>
```

The above example will output:

```
'42' is numeric
'1337' is numeric
'not numeric' is NOT numeric
'Array' is NOT numeric
'9.1' is numeric
```

**Where `ctype_digit()` and `is_numeric()` differ?**

Example comparing strings with integers:

```
<?php
    $numeric_string = '42';
    $integer        = 42;

    ctype_digit($numeric_string);  // true
    ctype_digit($integer);         // false (ASCII 42 is the * character)

    is_numeric($numeric_string);   // true
    is_numeric($integer);          // true

?>
```