# Check if first character of a string is letter or number in PHP?

Tags: php

Is there a way to check if the first character of a string is a letter or a number? I'm not really sure what function to use. Is there a way to check not using regex, as we have not learned that yet in my class.

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: @bcesars how exactly is that helpful to the question?

Comment: @JonathanKuhn How exactly this question is valid in SO without being _too broad_ or _primarily opinion based_ ?

Comment: [Get the first character](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972100/getting-the-first-character-of-a-string-with-str0) and then [check if it is a number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14230986/how-can-i-check-if-a-char-is-a-letter-or-a-number)

Answer (score 5):

I'd encourage you to read more about [strings in PHP](http://php.net/language.types.string). For example, you can dereference them like arrays to get individual characters.

```
$letters = 'abcd';
echo $letters[0];
```

There are also a handful of `ctype` functions. Check out, [`ctype_digit()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-digit.php) and [`ctype_alpha()`}(http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alpha.php).

```
ctype_digit($letters[0]); // false
ctype_alpha($letters[0]); // true
```

Putting these together, you should be able to do what you want.

Comment: Will throw a notice if the string is empty, so check !empty($string) first.

Answer (score 4):

You can access characters in a string just like an array index, so `$string[0]` is the first character.

Then you could use `is_numeric` to determine if the first character is a number.

```
$word1 = "string";
$word2 = "12345";

var_dump(is_numeric($word1[0])); // false
var_dump(is_numeric($word2[0])); // true
```

This should get you pretty close to what you're looking for, depending on how strictly you define a "letter." I'm guessing that you really mean "non-numeric."

Comment: *is a letter or a number* OP wants to check if it is a letter or a number

Comment: are special characters like #*!@#$% supposed to be in string.

Comment: @HemantMaurya Sure those are perfectly valid string characters