# How would I find out if the first character is a number or a letter?

Tags: php

Lets say I have:

```
_Example
_1979
```

How do we know if the character after `_` is a `number` or a `letter`? I am not familiar with `regex`.

This is what I am doing to only find strings starting with `_` and then I am removing the `_` as I am only using it for other reasons:

```
if (strpos($txt, '_') !== false) {
   $output = str_replace('_', ' ', $txt);
   echo $output;
  ...Now I should find if the first `character` is a `letter` or a `number`
```

Comment: `/^_\d.*$/` will match digits `/^_[a-z].*$/i` will match alpha characters.

Comment: @CD001 how would I use that to check if the first character is one or the other then do whatever afterwards?

Comment: `if(preg_match()) { ... }`

Comment: Learn about regular expressions.  Try playing with some here [https://regex101.com/](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: Something like `if(preg_match('/^_\d.*$/', $str)) { ... } elseif(preg_match('/^_[a-z].*$/i', $str)) { .... } else { ... doesn't match either ...}`

Comment: Ha! magic stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29039472/check-if-first-character-of-a-string-is-letter-or-number-in-php

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't want regex then PHP actually lets you access bytes from a string directly like this:

```
$string = '_1987';

// Since string indexing is zero-based, we want to check if
// the first char is an underscore and
// the second character is a digit
if( $string[0] === '_' && ctype_digit( $string[1] ) )
{
    echo 'underscore followed by digit!';

    // chop off the leading underscore
    $string = substr( $string, 1 );
}
else
{
    echo 'not underscore followed by digit!';
}
```

[Documentation](http://php.net/language.types.string#language.types.string.substr)

Comment: `if( ctype_digit( $string[1] ) )` needs to be `if( $string[0] == '_' && ctype_digit( $string[1] ) )` the check needs to be after _ sign

Comment: I will accept this as it isn't using regex and it's more readable for me, yet this question is a duplicate actually since there is one already https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29039472/check-if-first-character-of-a-string-is-letter-or-number-in-php

Comment: @RaymondNijland Good call, I missed that tidbit

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is perfect

Comment: @rob.m Glad I could help. Please see my updated answer because the compound `if(){}` block changes what the `else{}` block handles due to Raymond's comment.

Answer (score 0):

for this you could avoid regexp  .. you could simply use  is_numeric()

```
is_numeric(substr($txt, 1));
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php

Comment: or simpler `is_numeric($txt[1])`

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
if (is_numeric($txt[1])) ...
```

You can access the first letter of the string by using square brackets or by using substr, according to your needs.

```
if (is_numeric(substr($txt, 1))) ...
```

This will return either true or false

For reference

> http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php
>   http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

Comment: he's looking for the character after the _, which is the 2nd character, and since array index starts at 0, the correct position is 1

Comment: its cool, I thought the same and only after I've read it again, that I understood properly :P