# PHP detect if string starts with Alpha or Numeric

Tags: php

I am sorting out data from my database using PHP and needed to know if the string(varchar) value starts with a letter or a number, so i am writing a function to check this.

Below is my code, I got the first letter of the string and now my next step is to identify if its a Letter or a number,can PHP achieve this? any suggestions would be great thanks!

```
function StartWith($str) {

     return  $str[0];

}

echo StartWith('AdamSavior');
```

Comment: You can use is_numeric function 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php

Comment: http://us3.php.net/is_numeric use is_numeric

Comment: How about determining what letter it's already in database. It would be more efficient.

Comment: Check if it is numeric by is_numeric

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be more simple:

```
function StartWith($str)
{
    return is_numeric($str[0]) ? 'Number' : 'Letter';
}

echo StartWith('AdamSavior');
```

---

Since your task is in database, would be good if it is done with query

Answer (score 4):

The proper way using [***ctype_alpha***](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alpha.php) and [***ctype_digit***](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-digit.php) functions:

```
function startWith($str) {
    $c = $str[0];
    if (ctype_alpha($c)){
        return 'alpha';
    } else if (ctype_digit($c)){
        return 'numeric';
    } else {
        return 'other';
    }
}

echo startWith('AdamSavior') . PHP_EOL;
echo startWith('33man') . PHP_EOL;
echo startWith('---way') . PHP_EOL;
```

The output (consequtively):

```
alpha
numeric
other
```

Comment: Wow thanks the `other` was a bonus i was also thinking of getting if it start with a special character.

Comment: @KaoriYui, you're welcome

Answer (score 0):

You can use is_numeric() function. Have a look at this link

[How can I check if a char is a letter or a number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14230986/how-can-i-check-if-a-char-is-a-letter-or-a-number)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

function StartWith($str)
{
    if(is_numeric($str[0])) {
        return "Number";

    }else{
        return "Letter";
    }
}
echo StartWith('adamSavior');
```

Good luck!